# Замена адресной строки

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый вечер. Недавно для себя открыл что такое htaccess и пытался самостоятельно что-то делать с ним, пока не положил сайт. Вопрос. У меня есть адрес www.domen.ru/index.php как сделать так, чтобы адрес был такой www.domen.ru/game но заходил на тот же индекс.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

```
# включаем mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
# все перенаправления будут указываться относительно корня сайта
RewriteBase /

# перенаправляем game в index.php без редиректа
RewriteRule ^game$ index.php
```

При этом файл .htaccess должен лежать в корне сайта (рядом с index.php).